# Error (Xcode): No such file or directory Encountered error while archiving for device

Tags: ios, pipeline, build-error, flutter-ios-build, xcode-build-phase

ios folder in my Flutter app has 2 folders **Debug** and **Release**.
These folders contains firebase plist and json file for respective build type.
After creating those folders I have created following build phase script that checks if the build config is release or debug and then copies the respective file into the root.

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
# Name of the resource we're selectively copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

echo "Configuration ${CONFIGURATION}"
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
    # Get references to dev and prod versions of the GoogleService-Info.plist
    # NOTE: These should only live on the file system and should NOT be part of the target (since we'll be adding them to the target manually)
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/Release/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
    
    # Make sure the prod version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
    echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD ]
    then
        echo "No Production GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
        exit 1
    fi
    
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
    # Get references to dev and prod versions of the GoogleService-Info.plist
    # NOTE: These should only live on the file system and should NOT be part of the target (since we'll be adding them to the target manually)
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/Debug/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
    
    # Make sure the dev version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
    echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV ]
    then
        echo "No Development GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```

Both these folders are in .gitignore and created runtime in the pipeline
But my pipeline is not running successfully and is giving the following error

```
Archiving com.abc.xyz...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 12ABC3D456
Running pod install...                                             87.7s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode archive done.                                         157.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Debug: No such file or directory

Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Now if I add another step in my pipeline that adds the Debug folder without any files or anything, the pipeline succeeds.

What I want to know is, what necessitates the creation of the debug folder? If the build type is release then it shouldn't require existence of a Debug folder.